# trying to access an array: family[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to print the name of each person in order and I keep getting this error `family[i] is undefined`.

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);

for(var i = 0; i <= family.length; i++) {
    console.log(family[i].name);
}
```

Comment: simply not `<=` but `for(var i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {` http://jsfiddle.net/EJZ48/772/

Comment: That `family[I]` is undefined indicates that you are trying to access an index of `family` that does not exist.  Take a look at your loop and Google the term 'off by one error'.

Comment: As a side note, it's better practice to do `var family = [];` to create a new empty array instead of doing `var family = new Array();`.

Comment: Debug your program. Step through it line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop overshoots the bounds of the array. Try:

`for( var i = 0; i < family.length; i++ )`

Keep in mind that `array.length` will always be higher than the maximum array index, because the index starts at 0, while length starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the for loop as follows as you are trying to read undefined value at the end:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= family.length; i++) {
    console.log(family[i].name);
}
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
    console.log(family[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation